# Simple way to get value from DropDown menu in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make sure I store the correct value that the users are selecting from a dropdown menu in ReactJS. I am here modifying an existing code and showing the parts that I guess would be beneficial to understand the problem. Can anyone tell me an easy way to correctly set the value in my parameter? until now I am not able to store the value

many thanks

```
emphasized textimport React from "react";

import { Centered } from "meteor/empirica:core";

export default class ExitSurvey extends React.Component {
  static stepName = "ExitSurvey";
  state = { age: "", gender: "", country: "", strength: "", fair: "", feedback: "" , education: "", occupation: "xxxx"};


  handleChange = event => {
    const el = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState({ [el.name]: el.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  };

  selectCountry (val) {
    this.setState({ country: val });
  }



  render() {
    const { player } = this.props;
    const { age, gender, country, strength, fair, feedback, education, occupation} = this.state;

 return (
      <Centered>
        <div className="exit-survey">
          <h1> Exit Survey </h1>
          <p>
            Please submit the following code to receive your bonus:{" "}
            <strong>{player._id}</strong>.
          </p>
          <p>
            You final <strong>bonus</strong> is in addition of the{" "}
            <strong>1 base reward</strong> for completing the HIT.
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            Please answer the following short survey. You do not have to provide
            any information you feel uncomfortable with.
          </p>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

   <div>
          <label><b>Occupation:</b></label>
            <div>

              <select value={this.state.value}  onChange={this.handleChange}> 

                <option value="Personal-care">Personal care and service occupations</option>
                <option value="Sales">Sales and related occupations</option>
                <option value="Office-Admin">Office and administrative support occupations</option>
                <option value="Farming-Fishing">Farming, fishing, and forestry occupations</option>
                <option value="Construction">Construction and extraction occupations</option>
                <option value="Installation-Maintenance">Installation, maintenance, and repair occupations</option>
                <option value="Production">Production occupations</option>
                <option value="Transportation">Transportation and material moving occupations</option>
                <option value="Military">Military specific occupations</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>

              <p> hello :::: {this.state.occupation}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `state.value` which is `undefined` because you have no  property named `value` in your state. To solve for this, you need to add a property for the select element in your state.

```
state = {
  selectedValue: ''
  // this could also be a value for one of its options
  // e.g selectedValue: 'Personal-care'

  // add rest of your state values...
};
```

Your `handleChange` function is basically storing the name of the element and assigning the value to it. But you haven't initialized that property in the state. So when the component renders for the first time, you'll have no value set for the select element.

To fix this, modify your `handleChange` function to reflect the following...

```
handleChange = event => {
  const { value } = event.currentTarget;
  this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
};
```

Then, in your render function, update the select element to access the property stored in the state.

```
<select value={this.state.selectedValue}  onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

Comment: What's above is not what is in your code. Unless you mean you have updated your code with the above.

Comment: that is just similar to this statement in my code -->  handleChange = event => {
    const el = event.currentTarget;
    this.setState({ [el.name]: el.value });
  };

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain what's going on with your and where you have some issues

Comment: I have tried it, I am trying to make sure that it is working by printing the value in the screen and it is not updated -->               <p> hello :::: {this.state.selectedValue}</p>

Comment: I also want to ask if it is okay to have more than one handleChange() function because I can't change it for the other parameters in my survey page.

Comment: I don't know what you have in your code right now but this is what i've told you to do https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sun-5cowx